# Why PeerJs changes MediaStream when sending it to someone?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webrtc, peerjs, mediastream

### I am writing video chat app using Next.js 14, Express, socket.io, peerjs

**And the problem is that I send one stream and the user receives a changed one. And this is happens when I join a room with the camera turned off.**

*If I am already in the room and user joins this room*

```
useUpdateEffect(() => {
    if (!peer) return;

    socket.on(
      "user:joined",
      ({
        peerId: remotePeerId,
        muted: remoteMuted,
        visible: remoteVisible,
        name: remoteName,
        email: remoteEmail,
        image: remoteImage,
      }) => {
        toast.success(`${remoteName} joined`);
        // Calling new user
        console.log("My stream", stream?.getTracks());

        const call = peer.call(
          remotePeerId,
          stream as MediaStream, // my stream
          {
            metadata: {
              user: {
                email: data?.user?.email,
                name: data?.user?.name,
                image: data?.user?.image,
              },
              muted,
              visible,
            },
          },
        );
        call.on("stream", (remoteStream: MediaStream) => {
          console.log("User b stream", remoteStream.getTracks());
          addConnection({
            peerId: remotePeerId,
            connection: call,
            stream: remoteStream,
            muted: remoteMuted,
            visible: remoteVisible,
            name: remoteName,
            email: remoteEmail,
            image: remoteImage,
          });
        }); // On new user answer
      },
    );
    return () => {
      socket.off("user:joined");
    };
  }, [peer]);
```

*Me as a new user*

```
useUpdateEffect(() => {
    if (!peer) return;

    peer.on("call", (call: any) => {
      const { peer: remotePeerId, metadata } = call;
      const {
        user: remoteUser,
        muted: remoteMuted,
        visible: remoteVisible,
      } = metadata;

      call.answer(stream); // * answers incoming call with my stream
      console.log("My stream", stream?.getTracks());

      call.on("stream", (remoteStream: MediaStream) => {
        console.log("User a stream", remoteStream.getTracks());
        addConnection({
          peerId: remotePeerId,
          connection: call,
          stream: remoteStream,
          muted: remoteMuted,
          visible: remoteVisible,
          name: remoteUser.name,
          image: remoteUser.image,
          email: remoteUser.email,
        });
      }); // * new stream stream
      call.on("close", () =>
        toast.success(`${remoteUser.name} has left the room`),
      );
    });
  }, [peer]);
```

| Video tracks the first user sends | Video tracks that second user gets |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| **Video tracks that first user gets** | **Video tracks that second user sends** |
| [image] | [image] |

But I am expecting same tracks

#### **Here is the git link** https://github.com/ZAKHAROV-Artem/stack-overflow-problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found the solution :)

```html
<video
    ref={(node) => {
        if (node) node.srcObject = stream;
    }}
    autoPlay
    muted={true}
    className="aspect-video h-full w-full -scale-x-100 rounded-xl object-contain"
/>
<audio
    ref={(node) => {
        if (node) {
            node.srcObject = stream;
        }
    }}
    autoPlay
    muted={isMe}
/>
```

I think the following code bounds audio and video together, so as soon as we set `enabled=false` to audio it sets `muted=true` to video:

```js
await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: !muted,
    video: visible,
});
```

Maybe, it is possible to handle them and independent tracks, so if you know how, please share.